# Parsing mathematical expressions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm currently working on a python program to parse mathematical expression strings and evaluate them. I currently have the following code:

```
def evaluate(string):
    expr = [a for a in string if a!=" "]    
    for i,char in enumerate(expr):
        if char=="/":
            tmp = int(expr[i-1])/int(expr[i+1])
            expr[i+1] = tmp
            expr.pop(i)
            expr.pop(i-1)
        elif char=="*":
            tmp = int(expr[i-1])*int(expr[i+1])
            expr[i+1] = tmp
            expr.pop(i)
            expr.pop(i-1)
    for i,char in enumerate(expr):
        if char=="-":
            tmp = int(expr[i-1])-int(expr[i+1])
            expr[i+1] = tmp
            expr.pop(i)
            expr.pop(i-1)
        elif char=="+":
            tmp = int(expr[i-1])+int(expr[i+1])
            expr[i+1] = tmp
            expr.pop(i)
            expr.pop(i-1)
    return expr
```

I gave it the input `2 / 2 + 3 * 4 - 6 * 2` and it returned `["13", "-", "12"]`. Some steps I took to diagnose the problem was:
1. I moved the return expression to between the two for loops. The program then returned `["1.0", "+", "12", "-", "12"]`, so I know that the second loop is only evaluating the `+`.
2. I thought it might be a problem with the `-` block of code, but when I changed the input to `2 / 2 + 3 * 4 + 6 * 2` it output `["13", "+", "12"]`
3. I had it print out i in the second loop, and it printed out `0,1,2`. So there's the problem, it is only iterating through the first 3 elements of the list.
I get the feeling the problem has to do with modifying the list in place, and that screws up enumerate somehow. But what is the issue such that the first for loop works fine and it breaks the second? Any help would be appreciated as I am very confused

Comment: You need to recursively evaluate some expressions. Without addressing how to actually do the parsing,  `evaluate("2 * 3 + 6)` should be equivalent to `evaluate("2*3") + evaluate("6")`. Usually, you parse first, *then* evaluate a resulting structure.

Comment: Google "recursive descent parsing".

Comment: pop() method isn`t correct here, better use del list[i]

Comment: @OakenDuck this is bad idea, because then we`ll pop() elemnt every iteration whether the operation is performed or not

Comment: @n1tr0xs You're right, I'll remove my comment. The second for loop doesn't have to be there, though, it just makes the script go over the list twice.

Comment: On the off-chance that your only goal is to evaluate mathematical expressions from strings for personal use, you can use x = eval(string) to get the answer.  Note that this is unsafe if the string can be supplied from the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Use this improved code:

```
def evaluate(string):
    expr = [a for a in string if a!=" "]
    while( ('*' in expr) or ('/' in expr) or ('+' in expr) or ('-' in expr) ):
        for i,char in enumerate(expr):
            if char=="/":
                expr[i+1] = int(expr[i-1])/int(expr[i+1])
                del expr[i]
                del expr[i-1]
            elif char=="*":
                expr[i+1] = int(expr[i-1])*int(expr[i+1])
                del expr[i]
                del expr[i-1]
        for i,char in enumerate(expr):
            if char=="-":
                expr[i+1] = int(expr[i-1])-int(expr[i+1])
                del expr[i]
                del expr[i-1]
            elif char=="+":
                expr[i+1] = int(expr[i-1])+int(expr[i+1])
                del expr[i]
                del expr[i-1]
    return expr
```